# Display a list of objects and return values to view

Tags: c#, list, model-view-controller, web-applications

I have 2 models. In the first model "Checkmodel" is described how the object looks like. 
The second model "Checkmodels" creates a list of objects based on "Checkmodel".

Now I try to display it in my View but I just don't know how to do it.

1. Model "Checkmodel"

> ```
> namespace WebAppMVCtests.Models
> {
>     public class CheckModel
>     {
>         public string Name { get; set; }
>         public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
>         public CheckModel(string name, bool ischecked)
>         {
>             this.Name = name;
>             this.IsChecked = ischecked;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

2. Model "Checkmodels"

> ```
>  namespace WebAppMVCtests.Models {
>      public class CheckModels : List<CheckModel>
>      {
>          private List<CheckModel> modellist;
>
>          public CheckModels()
>          {
>              modellist = new List<CheckModel>();
>          }
>
>          public void Add(string name, bool ischecked)
>          {
>              CheckModel newModel = new CheckModel(name, ischecked);
>              this.Add(newModel);
>          }
>      } 
> }
> ```

Controller

```
namespace WebAppMVCtests.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    { 
        // GET: Home
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            CheckModels chmdls = new CheckModels();

            List<string> e = new List<string>();

            e.Add("John");
            e.Add("Kevin");
            e.Add("Mark");

            string name = "";
            bool ischecked = false;

            foreach (var dir in e)
            {
                CheckModel newCheckModel = new CheckModel(name, ischecked);

                chmdls.Add(newCheckModel);
            }
return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(List<CheckModel> list)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

View

```
@model WebAppMVCtests.Models.CheckModels
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(it => it[i].Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(it => it[i].IsChecked)
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    }

    <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />

}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing when view is displayed?

Comment: I will add my view. I try to display the list with a for loop but I always get a NULL exception.

Comment: Debug your view razor and see what do you get in `Model` ?

Comment: I get NULL but I don't get why. In the controller I create objects and then put them in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this in your Index method:

```
return View(chmdls);
```

Comment: Works but shouldn't it display the name? The NULL exception is gone and know I see 3 Check-boxes. And do you maybe know how I can get the values from the list? I want to to do something in my controller like: if(check ==  true){ "insert name into Database" }

Comment: Names were also displayed! my bad. I am still interested if you know how to pass the parameters to the controller.